# Searching For Users

Tags: facebook, search, facebook-graph-api, full-text-search, search-engine

I'm currently investigating a way to develop a website that will allow me to search for users of facebook and the outcome is to display some simple information to the user of my website about this person. so firstly a search will will display a list of users and then when the user clicks the name the basic information will be displayed.
This is part of a University application i am looking into creating for a final year project. i'm not asking for answers i'm just wondering is it possible to even use the api to integrate with a aspx.net project and do the searches i have explained.

any pointers would help greatly. This is my first ever post on this form and i hope to be an active user of the site.

Thanks Everyone
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Look at the search section of this document.